# What is the unit of selenium's Dimension(1200,600)?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, automation

I am automating an application where it is necessary to for the application to have 1200x600 pixel size of the browser. I am using a code like below to maximize(I don't want to use `dirver.manage().maximize()` code it has some problem with application).
Here the below is my code

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(1200,600);
//Resize the current window to the given dimension
driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
```

But still, the application is not compatible with this size. So can somebody tell what is the unit used int this 1200 and 600 in Dimention() constructor?
It is fine if some gives the equivalency value 1200x600 pixel value in Dimenstion(xxx,xxx).

Note: using google-chrome 65.x,windows 10.

Comment: The command sets the size of the outer window in pixels and not the size of the inner window/view-port which contains the web-page. Be also aware that windows limits the size of a window to the size of the desktop.

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver";,
        "/path/to/chromedriver");
 
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("window-size=800,480");
 
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

Try this.

Comment: Is there anything do I need import ?

Comment: @Hiten please post your code as a suggested answer as it would be easier to read (format the code) and I believe your answer is the correct one - it's what I would have posted.

Comment: I tried this code but this code is not at all maximizing the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main question here seems to be ***what is the unit used int this 1200 and 600 in Dimension() constructor?***.

### Class Dimension

As per the docs [*Dimension Class*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Dimension.html) is defined as :

```
public class Dimension
extends java.lang.Object
Similar to Point - implement locally to avoid depending on GWT.
```

### Class Point

As per the docs [Point](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Point.html) is defined as :

```
A copy of java.awt.Point, to remove dependency on awt.
```

### java.awt.Point

As per the docs [java.awt.Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/Point.html) is defined as :

```
public class Point
extends Point2D
implements Serializable

A point representing a location in (x,y) coordinate space, specified in integer precision.
```

### Point2D Class

As per the docs [Point2D Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html) is defined as :

```
The Point2D class defines a point representing a location in (x,y) coordinate space.
This class is only the abstract superclass for all objects that store a 2D coordinate. 
The actual storage representation of the coordinates is left to the subclass.
```

Digging out a bit more, [this documentation](https://www.developer.com/net/vb/article.php/626081/Java-2D-Graphics-The-Point2D-Class.htm) says :

> A point is a specification of a particular location in space.  It has neither height, nor width, nor depth.  Therefore, it cannot be rendered on your computer screen, although it might be possible to render a pixel on your screen that occupies a space generally specified by the point.  Hence, a point in our 2D space represents a location in that space commonly specified by a pair of coordinate values, horizontal (x) and vertical (y).
>
> This is similar to the notion of performing graphic operations in *Cartesian coordinates* the only difference is, in Cartesian coordinates the positive direction of y-displacement is normally up, while in our current frame of reference, the direction of positive y-displacement is down.  As in typical Cartesian coordinates, the direction of positive x-displacement is to the right.

Answer (score 1):

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver"); 
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
 options.addArguments("window-size=800,480"); 
 DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); 
 cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

 driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
 driver.get("https://google.com");
```

Try this code.
I tried this and it's perfectly working.

Comment: I tried this, but it is before creating webdriver object. but how can I set the size of already existing driver object(browser)?

Comment: you just need to set the capability of that existing driver.

Comment: Can you give a sample code please. I am not able to set for existing driver.

Comment: In my case, it is creating a new browser and leaving existing browser.

Comment: driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
you just need to pass "cap" in your existing driver when initialize.